# How to write first two bytes using minimal Modbus write register?

Tags: python, minimalmodbus

I am trying to figure out how to write first two bytes using minimalModbus write register command.
Register size - 240(unsigned 8 bit int array), I used write.registers command and passed the value as an array but write value is happening in 2 and 4th byte.

Example : 00 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Instead I want the result as 03 01 followed by other bytes. Please give some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

How are you using [`write_registers`](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apiminimalmodbus.html#minimalmodbus.Instrument.write_registers)?

I'd expect a list of 16-bit ints, so you may be able to simply write this as

```py
write_registers(address, [3, 1, ...])
```

Alternatively, you could use the much more verbose [`write_bits`](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apiminimalmodbus.html#minimalmodbus.Instrument.write_bits) to push *exactly* what you want

```py
write_bits(address, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...])
```

You can build a binary view of 16-bit blocks from your original ints like

```py
>>> list(map(int, "".join(f"{x:016b}" for x in [3, 1])))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Hi All,  I tried the above methods but got a different error as "value should be numerical"

Comment: write_register(registeraddress: int, value: Union[int, float], number_of_decimals: int = 0, functioncode: int = 16, signed: bool = False) → None[source]
Write an integer to one 16-bit register in the slave, possibly scaling it.

The slave register can hold integer values in the range 0 to 65535 (“Unsigned INT16”).        Is there a way to convert the Unsigned INT 16 to Unsigned INT 8 ?

Comment: @AswiniGovindarajan sorry, I'd had a typo in the second suggestion, but the first is `write_registers` with a plural **s**, not simply `.write_register` and I'd used an ellipsis to represent the rest of your input.. do yo get the same result with the different method and full input?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used minimalmodbus, but [the docs](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apiminimalmodbus.html#minimalmodbus.Instrument.write_register) suggest that the registers are 16-bits in size. This explains why each value you write is being padded by a byte. 1 and 3 are represented as 0x0001 and 0x0003 in 16 bits. You need to pack your two bytes into a single 16-bit value.

While you can do this with some [bitwise operators](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/), it may be more straightforward to use the [struct library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) for this.

You can create your packed value like so:

```
bin_data = struct.pack('BB', (3,1)) # Turn into bytes 0x0301
packed_value = struct.unpack('H', bin_data)  # 259 or 769 (depending on endianness)
```

Then try passing `packed_value` to `write_register()`. You may have to play with endianness (`<H` vs. `>H`) to get the order you want.

Comment: Also need some inputs on converting 16bit into 8bit

Comment: Can you explain more? What do you mean converting 16bit to 8bit?